# iframe breakout is double back button

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I am using an iframe which is called from a bookmarklet, which calls an html page, which shows a user details about the page they are looking at. To close the iframe I am using:

```
<a href="<? echo $original_page_url; ?>" target="_parent">X Close Window</a>
```

This closes the iframe and leaves the user on the same page they were on. Which is ideal, however, as far as the browser is concerned they have to press the back button twice to get back to where they were before e.g. some search results, as they have essentialy been to the current page twice consecutively. Once originally, then again when I close the iframe.

Is there a better way to do this that can avoid this?

This is the bookmarklet code to spawn the iframe:

```
javascript:(function%20(d)%20{var%20modal%20=%20document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src',%20'http://blah.com/info.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&page_title='+document.title);
modal.setAttribute('scrolling',%20'no');modal.className%20=%20'modal';
document.body.appendChild(modal);var%20c%20=%20document.createElement('link');
c.type%20=%20'text/css';c.rel%20=%20'stylesheet';
c.href%20=%20'//blah.com/css/iframe.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);}(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').style.display='none';
```

Moreover, you can close this iframe inside the iframe:

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframeId').style.display='none';
```

This will get the iframe object from parent and set its visibility to hidden.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't set an id for the iframe (or is that the createElement?), this is kind of new to me actually, learning as much and fast as possible - amended the question... is there a way to set id(if thats not it) and then add your suggestion? I tried: <a href=# onclick="parent.document.getElementById('iframe').style.display='none'">X Close Window</a> but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.replace`

Maybe like this

```
<a onclick="window.location.replace('<? echo $original_page_url; ?>')">X Close Window</a>
```

Comment: That simply swaps the original url with what's in the iframe and leaves the frame there - not good.